# Unable to write a jest test for mongodb code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jestjs

I'm trying to write my first jest test that will test a database call.  But I can't get a basic mongo test going.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@shelf/jest-mongodb": "^2.1.0",
    "jest": "^27.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "^4.1.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "@shelf/jest-mongodb"
  }
}
```

I went to https://jestjs.io/docs/mongodb and grabbed this example and pasted into `db.test.js`

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

describe('insert', () => {
  let connection;
  let db;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    connection = await MongoClient.connect(global.__MONGO_URI__, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });
    db = await connection.db(global.__MONGO_DB_NAME__);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await connection.close();
    await db.close();
  });

  it('should insert a doc into collection', async () => {
    const users = db.collection('users');

    const mockUser = {_id: 'some-user-id', name: 'John'};
    await users.insertOne(mockUser);

    const insertedUser = await users.findOne({_id: 'some-user-id'});
    expect(insertedUser).toEqual(mockUser);
  });
});
```

Then I ran these commands:

```
npm install
npm run test
```

And I got these errors:

```
 FAIL  ./db.test.js
  ● insert › should insert a doc into collection

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')

       6 |
       7 |   beforeAll(async () => {
    >  8 |     connection = await MongoClient.connect(global.__MONGO_URI__, {
         |                                    ^
       9 |       useNewUrlParser: true,
      10 |     });
      11 |     db = await connection.db(global.__MONGO_DB_NAME__);

      at new ConnectionString (node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/src/index.ts:98:23)
      at parseOptions (node_modules/mongodb/src/connection_string.ts:249:15)
      at new MongoClient (node_modules/mongodb/src/mongo_client.ts:327:34)
      at Function.connect (node_modules/mongodb/src/mongo_client.ts:507:27)
      at db.test.js:8:36


  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'close')

      13 |
      14 |   afterAll(async () => {
    > 15 |     await connection.close();
         |                      ^
      16 |     await db.close();
      17 |   });
      18 |

      at db.test.js:15:22
```

It seems as if jest is unable to create a mongo instance?  What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i figured it out.  Here's my final solution:

My package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@shelf/jest-mongodb": "^2.1.0",
    "jest": "^27.2.4"
  }
}
```

I also needed a `jest.config.js` which looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '@shelf/jest-mongodb',
};
```

The example test given by https://jestjs.io/docs/mongodb is buggy. So I fixed it in my db.test.js which now looks like this:

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

describe('insert', () => {
  let connection;
  let db;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    connection = await MongoClient.connect(global.__MONGO_URI__, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });
    db = await connection.db(global.__MONGO_DB_NAME__);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await connection.close();
    if(db.close) {
      await db.close();
    }
  });

  it('should insert a doc into collection', async () => {
    const users = db.collection('users');

    const mockUser = {_id: 'some-user-id', name: 'John'};
    await users.insertOne(mockUser);

    const insertedUser = await users.findOne({_id: 'some-user-id'});
    expect(insertedUser).toEqual(mockUser);
  });
});
```

Then I ran `npm install; npm run test;`.  And I see the test run and succeed.